# GWT - configuring Gilead problem

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, dto, gilead

I followed [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html) and decided to use [Gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/) to avoid writing DTO boilerplate.

But with no success yet. I did as tutorial advices:

1. Made my POJO on server side extend `net.sf.gilead.pojo.java5.LightEntity`

   public class Attachment extends LightEntity implements Serializable { ... }
2. Made my server-side service implementation extend `net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService`

   public class LoginServiceImpl extends PersistentRemoteService implements LoginService { ...}
3. Configured beanManager exactly as in tutorial.

When I tried to use server-side class, that extends Gilead's LightEntity, I get error as If there were no Gilead, just restricted server code.

Here are JARs I included to my build path:

[image]

Comment: I gave up on Gilead, I am writing plain DTOs. However, I'll leave this question open, maybe we'll find answer.

Answer (score 0):

change your MusicStoreServiceImpl() to

```
public MusicStoreServiceImpl() {
gileadHibernateUtil.setSessionFactory(com.google.musicstore.util.HibernateUtil
    .getSessionFactory());

PersistentBeanManager persistentBeanManager = new PersistentBeanManager();
persistentBeanManager.setPersistenceUtil(gileadHibernateUtil);
StatelessProxyStore sps = new StatelessProxyStore();
sps.setProxySerializer(new GwtProxySerialization());
persistentBeanManager.setProxyStore(sps);
setBeanManager(persistentBeanManager);
```

}